# Optimize simd instructions (mov) for arm64 to pack alternating bytes into contiguous bytes (hex to uint64_t)

Tags: macos, assembly, simd, arm64, neon

I have this V6.16b register : `0a,0b,0c,0d,0e,0f,07,08,0a,0b,0c,0d,0e,0f,07,08`
and the goal is : `ab,cd,ef,78,ab,cd,ef,78`

I did it like this :

```
movi v7.8h,   0x04            // 04,00,04,00,04,00,04,00,04,00,04,00,04,00,04,00
ushl v6.16b,  v6.16b,  v7.16b // a0,0b,c0,0d,e0,0f,70,08,a0,0b,c0,0d,e0,0f,70,08
movi v8.8h,   0xf8            // f8,00,f8,00,f8,00,f8,00,f8,00,f8,00,f8,00,f8,00
ushl v10.8h,  v6.8h,   v8.8h  // 0b,00,0d,00,0f,00,08,00,0b,00,0d,00,0f,00,08,00
orr  v10.16b, v10.16b, v6.16b // ab,0b,cd,0d,ef,0f,78,08,ab,0b,cd,0d,ef,0f,78,08

mov v10.b[1], v10.b[2]
mov v10.b[2], v10.b[4]
mov v10.b[3], v10.b[6]
mov v10.b[4], v10.b[8]
mov v10.b[5], v10.b[10]
mov v10.b[6], v10.b[12]
mov v10.b[7], v10.b[14] // ab,cd,ef,78,ab,cd,ef,78,ab,0b,cd,0d,ef,0f,78,08
```

It works, but is there a way to do it with fewer instructions? (in particular the mov)

Comment: Which version of the ARMv8 architecture can you use?  Sounds like you want a shuffle (possibly `uzp1` and `uzp2` ad suggested by Peter Cordes) followed by `sli` to combine the nibbles.

Comment: uzp1 replace the 7 mov. its ok, now i try 1 ushl instead of 2 and the orr (before the packing step)

Comment: Use `sli` instead of `ushl` + `orr`.

Comment: @fuz: [macos] presumably implies at least M1.  which is ARMv8.5-A.  Are SLI and UZP2 not baseline ARMv8 ASIMD?  (Thanks for the pointer, I'd forgotten about SLI.)

Comment: @fuz Yes thank you!

Comment: I dont't know the arm version, its for  apple M2.

Comment: @PeterCordes They are baseline, but it's easier to know what architecture level is needed rather than having to potentially think of separate solutions for different levels.

Comment: @Stephane: Please don't edit answers into the question.  Post your own answer if necessary.  But in this case I'd already edited my answer, so accepting it and maybe commenting to confirm that the untested code was correct is the most you should do.  I'd recommend rolling back your last edit to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have zero-extended nibbles unpacked in big-endian order to pack into bytes?
Like for strtol for hex -> integer, after some initial processing to map ASCII hex digits to the integer digits they represent.

For your original setup where you want to pack bytes from the even positions, [`UZP1`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/UZP1--vector-), but you can optimize the shift/orr step as well.

Instead of the first block of 2x ushl + orr, maybe `shl v10.8h, v6.8h, #12` / `orr` to get the bytes you want in the odd elements, garbage (unmodified) in the even elements.  (Counting from 0, the `0a` element since I think you're writing your vectors in least-significant-first order where wider left shifts move data to the right across byte boundaries).  **Or better, `sli v6.8h, v6.8h, #12`** ([Shift-Left and Insert](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/SLI--vector-), where bits keep their original values in the positions where the left shift created zeros.)

**For the packing step,** [`UZP2`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/UZP2--vector-) should work to take the odd-numbered vector elements (starting with 1) and pack them down into the low 8 bytes.  (Repeated in the high 8 bytes if you use the same vector as both source operands.)

```
// produces the same result as all your code
//  in the bottom 8 bytes of v10
 sli   v6.8h, v6.8h, #12       //a0,ab,c0,cd,e0,ef,70,78, a0,ab,c0,cd,e0,0f,70,78
 uzp2  v10.16b, v6.16b, v6.16b //ab,cd,ef,78,ab,cd,0f,78, ab,cd,ef,78,ab,cd,0f,78

// rev64 v10.8b, v10.8b         // if you want a uint64_t in proper order
```

(I notice you have an `e0` byte.  `(0xe0 as u16) << 12` shifts out the bit to become 0, if that wasn't a typo for `0x0e`)

---

This leaves your data in big-endian byte order if that was the order across pairs of nibbles. **You might need a byte-shuffle `tbl` instead or `uzp2`** to reverse the order into a `uint64_t` while packing.  Or if you're only doing this for one number at a time (so loading a shuffle-control constant would take another instruction that can't be hoisted out of a loop) perhaps `rev64 v10.8b, v10.8b` after `uzp2`.  Or `rev64` with `v10.16b` to do two u64 integers in two halves of the vector.

---

For packing pairs of bytes, shift-right and accumulate [`usra`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/USRA--vector-) by `#4` can also do that in one instruction (shift and accumulate), since ORR, ADD, and insert are equivalent when the set bits don't overlap.  But it would give you `0xba` not `0xab`, shifting the second byte down to become the high half of a u8.  `rev16` + `usra` would work, but `shl` + `orr` is also 2 instructions and probably cheaper, probably running on more execution units on at least some CPUs.  And `sli` is even better, thanks @fuz.

There is no `usla`.  A multiply-accumulate could be used with a power-of-2 multiplier, but might be slower on some CPUs than `shl` + `orr` and would require a vector constant.  And certainly worse than `sli`.

Comment: yes its hexa -> bytes, UZP1 replace the multiples mov, thanks. now i  l try with one ushl instead of 2 and the orr.

Comment: `sli` seems like the right choice to combine the nibbles.

Comment: @Stephane: updated with an even better version thanks to fuz's suggestion; we can shift-left and merge in a single instruction.

Comment: @Peter Cordes : Yes Its correct , i tested and it works.Thank you